# how to add [formControlName] for nested input type in Angular

Tags: angular

Angular2, I have multiple input type radio initialise in loop. I am using [formControlName], and issue is all input types have same ng-reflect-form-control-name in generated code, hence ngModel fails.

Currently in code [formControlName]="question.key" where I need this to be [formControlName]="opt.key" but then it throw error if I do so.

question.key is the main question Id and opt.key is sub-question id

I need help to assign unique key for each input of type radio separate key 'opt.key', not sure what I am missing???

### error

```
Cannot find control with name: 'c20ae971-bbf4-4317-aa6e-3d0ccd6a7edf'
```

c20ae971-bbf4-4317-aa6e-3d0ccd6a7edf is value of opt.key in my current instance

### template

```
 <div class="grid-row" *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
     <div class="flex-item">{{opt.subQuestionTitle}}</div>
        <div *ngFor="let sub_opt of opt.subOption">
           <label class="flex-item">                               
               <input type="radio" [formControlName]="question.key" [value]="sub_opt.key"> <span>{{sub_opt.selectedOptionState}}{{opt.key}}</span>
           </label>     
     </div>
    </div>
```

### component

```
else  if(questionElementType=="matrixRadio")
 {
   let _martrixRadio = new MatrixQuestion ({
     questionId: questionsList[key].questionId,
     key: questionsList[key].questionId,     

     options:  questionsList[key].subQuestions.map(function(item){
       return {"key": item.questionDetail.questionId, "subQuestionTitle": item.questionDetail.title, "selectedOption":this.getSubAnswer(questionsList[key].answer, item.questionDetail.questionId) ,subOption:                                                                   
                      item.preDefineAnswerOptions.map(function(subItem){
                      return {"name": item.ReferenceKey, "key":subItem.preDefineAnswerOptionId, "value":subItem.text ,"displayOrder":subItem.displayOrder, "selectedOptionState": subItem.preDefineAnswerOptionId ==this.getSubAnswer(questionsList[key].answer, item.questionDetail.questionId)? "true" :"false"}
                     }.bind(this))             
             }
           }.bind(this)), 
   });
```

### matrix class

```
 export class MatrixQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
 controlType = 'matrixRadio';
  options: {subQuestionTitle: string; name:string, key: string, value: string}[] = [];

 constructor(options: {} = {}) {
  super(options);
  this.options = options['options'] || [];
 }
}
```

### question base class

```
export class QuestionBase<T>{
consultationId: string;
questionId: string;
questionElementId:string;
questionType:string;
title:string;
value: T;
displayId:string;
key: string;
label: string;
required: boolean;
order: number;
controlType: string;


constructor(options: {
    consultationId?:string,
    questionId?:string,
    questionElementId?:string,
    questionType?:string,
    title?:string,
    value?: T,
    displayId?:string;
    key?: string,
    label?: string,
    required?: boolean,
    order?: number,
    controlType?: string
  } = {}) {
  this.consultationId = options.consultationId,
  this.questionId = options.questionId,
  this.questionElementId = options.questionElementId,
  this.questionType = options.questionType,
  this.title = options.title,
  this.value = options.value;
  this.displayId = options.displayId;
  this.key = options.key || '';
  this.label = options.label || '';
  this.required = !!options.required;
  this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
  this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
 }
}
```

Comment: You are rightly using [formControlName]="question.key" as all the radio option in a group should have the same control name i.e. question.key. Looks like you need to concentrate on the first error that you mentioned (".. ngModel fails"). Just make sure all options for a single questions have the same formControlName. Also refer this : https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9457 (not exactly related but helpful)